# How to link a UIView to a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

This is how i want the app to go. A person can design what ever view they want on InterfaceBuilder. In my code, I then take that view on interface builder an hook it up to a UICollectionViewCell.

So that way, their custom created view can be can be placed on many UICollectionViewCells.

So basically what I am asking is: how can I setup the cell for a UICollectionView with the following conditions:

1. Programmer will use interface builder to create the view (a UIView) for the cell
2. The programmer will not use a UICollectionView or UICollectionViewCell on interface builder.
3. Programmer will just create a normal UIView on interface builder, which my code will then take and hook into a UICollectionViewCell through code.

The goal of what i'm trying to do is to create a custom control that a programmer can use. The programmer only needs to design the  UIView and my code will handle the rest.

Is there any way to take a UIView from IB and hook it into a UICollectionViewCell with code? I am stuck.

The function i have looked at so far is the this one, but i'm not sure how to link the view to the UICollectionViewCell class.

```
func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

**EDIT** - Another potential solution i was thinking about was

1. Using NSKeyedArchiver to make a copy of the view that the user has InterfaceBuilder.
2. Save that copy
3. Create copies using NSKeyedUnarchiver

But this way out would be slow i think. Any one has any good ideas?

Comment: You can do it using xib's. You have to subclass UIView and then you have to load that view as a collection view cell.

Comment: Interesting problem. The only way I'm thinking about now is to  create, add (with autolayouts) and remove your UIView in reusable UICollectionViewCell. But this solution has performance drawback.

Comment: @BharatModi Ok, i have 1 questions on this. That solution would not allow a programmer to add the UIView to the IB right?

Comment: @razor28 i was thinking of a way to do this using NSKeyedArchiver to make a copy of the view the programmer created on interface builder, but KeyedArchiver is slow.  I am not sure how to implement your solution. Are you saying, to remove the subView of the collectionViewCell, and thenadd the view the programmer created from interface builder?

Comment: @Jay. Yes, You understand my opinion right. Just add and remove content of CollectionViewCell everytime it is called. So you will create base UICollectionViewCell with reuse identifier and then operate with this cell

Comment: I am talking about creating subclass of UIView which will have its separate xib, where one can design the view as he wish to.

Comment: You can use this to grab your UIView subclass out of a nib: `MyViewClass* myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewClassNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
` (not in Swift but you get the drift)

Comment: @BharatModi it worked. Place an answer so i can accept it. Btw, as an extra question, is there a way to but a separate NIB file on the story board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of you commenters mentioned.

1. Create a separate XIB file.
2. Design the view on the XIB file however you want.
3. You can then capture your view in swift like so:

> ```
> // Create the custom view 
> var customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("nameOfYourXib", owner: self,options: [:])[0] as! UIView
> // Add the subview to the cell
> cell.addSubview(customView)
> ```

5. In your customCollectionViewCell, add this view as a subView, and presto.

Comment: Lookin for the answer and see your comment. Thank you! But..

1. What about reuse? Is it use the same cell and creating a new custom UIView to add to the reused cell? If yes, how is performance?

2. Is it possible to use custom view just programmatically without using .xib?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using xib's. You have to subclass UIView and then you have to load that view as a collection view cell. This way you can design as much as different view's and you can use/load any view as collectionView cell you wish.

There might have other ways also to load view inside collection, what i tried for you and which was work is this:

```
//Dequeue cell 
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

//Create instance of view you wish to load as cell
let customView =     CustomView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))

//Add the view inside cell
 cell.addSubview(customView)
```

Edit/Update:

**Btw, as an extra question, is there a way to but a separate NIB file on the story board?**

No, this is not possible, You can not simply add a UIView on storyboard, you must first add a UIViewController to load your view inside. Storyboards are nothing but collection of xib's, the difference is you must have a UIViewController to hold/load your view.